# IOS7 How to access a object of an UIViewController from an other one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS so i hope i will be understandable.

Let's say i have 3 viewControllers : VC1, VC2, VC3.
Each one of them inherits a class named "BaseController" which contain an UImageView.

In the storyboard, i have : NavigationController -> VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 and each UImageView has been linked to the "BaseController" property :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *signalIcon;
```

I need to change the image in the ViewController displayed, in response to an event handled by VC1.

So i want to access from VC1 the UImageView of the ViewController displayed but i can't figure out how to do that.

I know how to get the UIVewController displayed :

```
UIViewController *uiVC = [self.navigationController topViewController];
```

but i can't access its UImageView. I tried with the restoration id but still not working.

Is it possible to do what i want or do i need to change my way of doing?

Comment: you need to declare the property on the .h file to make it global

Comment: also you should call BaseCOntroller *uiVc ......instead UIViewCOntroller *uiVC ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this would do the trick:

```
BaseController *uiVC = [self.navigationController topViewController];
// Set the image
uiVC.signalIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Comment: It should be the BaseController instead of UIViewController, you might edit your answer

Comment: Thx a lot, that's exactly what i needed !